# How to substract two values from same column using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

> I have a tabel named reading which has following columns, I want to
> find difference between each two values in the same column that is
> Units , and also  find average of all the difference in sequelize orm
> (node js).

```
    Id.  Units.  
    1.    1000.
    2.    1005
    3.    1006
    4.    1003
```

```
I want to find difference between each two values like:
1000 - 1005 = 5
1005 - 1006 = 6
1006 - 1003 = 3
```

> And find average of all the difference in sequelize orm (node js) how to find it

Comment: how come 1000 - 1005 = 5 and 1005 - 1006 = 6?

Comment: I don't see the comparisons of 1000 - 1003, 1000 - 1006 and other variations. Please clarify what combinations you're interested in